# C# windows service network credentials

Tags: c#, windows, networking, service, credentials

i developed a windows service in C# using VS 2019 its task get ip address and send it in txt file to local drive of my computer, until now its run perfect.

but when i execute this windows service to other computer and change destination to protected local network access become denied, however vbscript run normaly and can copy any folder and files to same network with my acount already saved in this computer.

my question why windows service doesn't use the same account to grant access to network as vbscript ?

what is the best solution to solve this issue ?

thanks in advance.

i tried to use System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem
LocalService
NetworkService
user

wihtout result

Comment: Are you an Admin?  A vbscript will run As Admin.  With c# if you are inside Visual Studio Admin is not automatically granted.  You need to start VS by right click VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  The c# executable will run As Admin.  The issue is just inside VS.

Comment: no iam talking about windows service running out of visual studio and not installed. in this computer.

Comment: @jdweng A vbscript will run as admin, what does that mean??

Comment: You need to give the machine account the correct permissions on the network share.

Comment: The VB script runs because it is running as ADMIN.  The c# is not running because it is NOT being run As Admin.

Comment: i checked it to run as administrator in properties but still the same issue